# Yii update row fails to update 2 variables at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-events

We need to update 2 parameters in one row from DB: `actInTime` and the `stat`.

Based on the current time the status can be 'Working(L)' or 'Working'.

`stat` is DB is defined as an ENUM with 'Working(L)' and 'Working' as the values.

```
$shiftData = ShiftDetails::model()->findByPk($shift["shiftID"]);
if(($curentTime - strtotime($shiftData->planInTime)) > 600) {
    $shiftData->stat = 'Working(L)';
}
else {
    $shiftData->stat = 'Working';
}
$shiftData->actInTime = Yii::app()->Date->now();
$shiftData->save();
```

The issue we face is not repeatable.
Some time both `actInTime` and `stat` is getting updated, but some times `stat` is not. `actInTime` is updating always without any issues

Comment: we tried with changing into VARCHAR. Still the issue exists. :(
Also the time Zones are same.

Comment: based on time that IF statement is functioning properly.
i tried to put LOG there also am getting the proper stat  values.
but its not updating into server.